# How to create a coupon code generator in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, e-commerce

Can anyone suggest any way to generate coupon codes for rails 4? its for a e commerce app in rails from scratch using stripe as a payment solution?

Comment: Consider explaining your question better, or it might get downvoted (and eventually closed). See this: [How should I ask questions?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How long is the code, could same letters be used more than once? do you want it alphanumeric or just letters? add some specs to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small example

```
letters = (0..9).to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a # add or remove possibilities
letters.sample(10).join #or any length you want
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, i am quite new to rails which is why the question might lack clarity. If i wanted this to appear on the users profile page as an option to be generated what would be my next steps with regards to incorporating this?

Comment: create a called for example 'generate_coupon` when you want to generate a new coupon you'd do something like `coupon=generate_coupon`

Comment: @JoshuaRountree well this code can't really know what's already saved in the database, so I think you'll need to check your self if this code was saved before in the database or not, using a loop of some sort, to make it less expensive you might want to generate and test multiple codes at once instead of doing one test per code.

Answer (score 7):

```
def generate_token
  loop do
    token = "YOUR_APP_NAME-#{SecureRandom.hex[0, 4].upcase}"
    break token unless YourModel.where(token: token).first
  end
end
token = generate_token
```

you can use above method to generate random token which will check the uniqueness in token filed of YourModel.

Comment: I'm not using this but I up-voted.  It is much a better solution.  That said I'd try 3 times before breaking